# Подключить React App к БД используя MVC паттерн ну или 3х уровневое

Tags: c#, reactjs, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Есть React App, нужно подключить его к БД используя MVC, в БД есть сохранённые процедуры и нигде не могу найти, как их описать в Web Application по аналогии с 3-х уровневым приложением или же если это прям несбываемые мечты, то в принципе можно и попробывать поключить через 3-х уровневое преложение, если так можно, в общем какой из вариантов будет самый лучший и не прийдётся описывать процедуры БД в C# вручную?

Comment: [Tutorial: Call an ASP.NET Core web API with JavaScript](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-javascript?view=aspnetcore-6.0). Делаем стандартное WebAPI, которое работает с БД. К этому API обращаемся из React.

Comment: [Use React with ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/react?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) - вот ещё ссылка для старта

Comment: Я это и искал, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

[Tutorial: Call an ASP.NET Core web API with JavaScript](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-javascript?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Там всё описано, спасибо [Alexander Petrov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/184217/alexander-petrov)